# Netbeans Rich Client Platform RCP application as a Web Service Client

Tags: java, web-services, soap, netbeans

I am trying to find out information about how to use the Netbeans Rich Client Platform (RCP) for a Web Service client (SOAP webservice) but i am struggling to find any tutorials or examples specifically for web service clients.

Are there any examples or guides anywhere?

Comment: Consuming a web service inside a NetBeans RCP application should not be different to consuming a web service in any other Java application. So just look out for tutorials on consuming web services

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is from another post but it looks promising...

http://tdamir.blogspot.com/2008/03/netbeans-platform-based-web-service.html